# ASP.NET MVC 4 Design pattern for creating similar views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

Looking for a design pattern for the following scenario

Many Categories
          -> Search page
          -> Details page

Both search and details pages for each category are similar, i.e, have common sections with varying number of fields(some might be common)

The type of category would be determined by the user at the application start.

How should i organize the proj. structure, have a single view and differentiate elements by category type field in model,
or can i have different folders for each category with views for each category type

### .Any better design idea?

Decided to go with different views per category( made folders per category)
and partial views for common sections on each page

Comment: Just spread out every similar section into a Partial Views and then use it everywhere you need!

Comment: Multiple controller could call the save view. Or have multiple view but load similar ascx files in them.

Comment: If the view models share the same properties yet have different implementations you can use interfaces. ISearchViewModel, ISearchDetails, etc.